# Why do some modules show with blue names and some with white names

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I downloaded the code for HannahMirror from git hub. I noticed that the under the various modules, the editor displays their names in different colors.

In the screenshot below Birthday and Forecast are blue while the rest are white, they are all public classes.

Here is the link to her GitHub: https://github.com/HannahMitt/HomeMirror

[image: Android Studio]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue color indicates that the file has been modified locally and the changes have not been committed.

For more information: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-status-highlights.html

Comment: by commited you mean like towards github?

Comment: @D.Zou If using git, committed to your local repository. Pushing to a remote is not highlighted in the IDE.